# Deploying web application on-site

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, deployment, vs-web-application-project

I have been deploying web applications on my server for all clients.But now I want to deploy a web application on client site..by which he means they should be able to use the application on their network only and could be used without internet.Havent really used IIS or Azure that much, are these what I am looking for ? Kindly direct me to the right direction.Is this requirement even valid?

It is an asp.net web app and uses sql server database made on Visual Studio.

PS: I am not sure if i am allowed to ask such questions here but help me out.

Comment: First step would be to know which type of infrastructure the client has... How did you even deploy sites for your clients without using IIS if you're developing in .NET ? You must have done some kind of IIS configuration at some point...

Comment: @LaurentS. - Not at all.I upload my website files on the server directly and it works all fine.Never used IIS

Comment: Hopefully your client will have his own IT guys taking care of infrastructure, else I guess you will have to learn. It's anyway really helfull to know the basics of webserver management so that not everything just happens "by magic".

Comment: I am planning to learn IIS and Azure pretty soon.That is a whole different story though.Right now I am just looking for a direction